# angular controller $scope symbol _

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
App.controller('todoController', function ($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view

    $scope.todos = [{ name: 'angular', done: false }];
    $scope.clearTodo = function () {

        $scope.todos = _.filter($scope.todos, function (todo) {
            return !todo.done;
        });
    };
});
```

Problem-can not find symbol _.
What I need to add? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the `underscore.js` file to the `<head>` in the `index.html` page (`<script>`)?

Comment: Yes.

but after your question I've added `underscore.d.ts`, and it works!!
=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_.filter is a part of the Underscore.js 'utility belt' library. Include

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

inside of your 'head' section in your HTML.